# Web Scraping with R - Difficulties with css and Xpath

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have been using rvest for a while now on simple websites.

But now I am facing difficulties when tryng to extract an information from the following website:

[Example page](https://www.reclameaqui.com.br/net-servicos-tv-banda-larga-e-telefone/conta-fora-do-acordado_-EeZZRgj5BoPsHK7/)

I have tried using both CSS and XPath, using the Rvest package, but without success.

```
library(rvest);library(magrittr)
#Trying to extract the body using selectorGadget's css
site="https://www.reclameaqui.com.br/net-servicos-tv-banda-larga-e-telefone/conta-fora-do-acordado_-EeZZRgj5BoPsHK7/"
read_html(site)%>%html_nodes(css=".complain-body .ng-binding")%>%html_text()
#[1] NA
```

I need to extract the **title** and the **main body text**.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried to extract? Are you using selectorGadget? Which CSS or xpath have you tried?.

Comment: It looks like it might be dynamically generated.  If so, you will need to use something like `RSelenium` that simulates a browser

Comment: @RicardoFernandesCampos
For example, if I right click on the body text and inspect the element, I obtain the following Xpath:

//*[@id="complain-detail"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/p


But when using html_nodes, it returns empty.

Comment: @AndrewGustar
What function of RSelenium would you recommend?